# Javascript draggable issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I can't draggable my label in my div. My div is draggabling and my label too. When i close draggabling my div i can draggable my label . but i cant draggable together them. how can i so

```
<div id="DraggableDiv" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="divKolon ui-resizable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="margin-left: 0px; position: relative; height: 171.545px; width: 367.545px;">
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90; display: block;"></div>
<span class="label label-danger col-xs-1" id="drag0" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">testLabel</span>
</div>
```

And my JavaScript Code.

```
$(".DraggableDiv").draggable();
$(".drag0").draggable();
```

Comment: can you do a fiddle please?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DLQsX/396/

Comment: do u want make both container (id="DraggableDiv") and label (id="drag0") dragable?

Comment: yes sir ,  I have alotof DraggableDiv And I want Draggable Label's from oneof to another.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z34pc5k0/3/  This is my Project on the fiddle.. I want to Draggable too my Span's

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to this cancel `draggable` on specific element. like this.

**http://jsfiddle.net/z34pc5k0/**

```
  $("#DraggableDiv").draggable({
    cancel: "#drag0"
  });

  $("#drag0").draggable();
```

https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel

Comment: I have Alot of Label :/ and its programatically :/ i dont know witch one is drag 1-2-3-4-5.....

Comment: then generate a speicific class for non dragable elements.

Comment: but how can i do this ? :(

Comment: how do u generate labels? text me on skype I will try to help u

Comment: I solve it This Code block

$(MyDivAdd).draggable ({
        containment : EklenecekDiv
      });